# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'open_account' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make an economy system for my discord bot. I followed a tutorial on youtube and the only thing I change was that I added it in cogs.

**Error:**

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'open_account' is not defined
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\liene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 965, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\liene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 970, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\liene\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 196, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: NameError: name 'open_account' is not defined
```

**Place where the error message told me the error was:**

```
class Economy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        await open_account(ctx.author)
        user = ctx.author
        users = await get_bank_data()

        wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

        em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", colour = discord.Color.green())
        em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
        em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = bank_amt)

        await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

**Full code:**

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import os
import random
from discord.ext.commands import Cog, BucketType
from discord.ext.commands import BadArgument
from discord.ext.commands import command, cooldown

os.chdir("C:\\Users\\liene\\OneDrive\\Dators\\Gabriels\\bot\\Rocketman")

class Economy(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client

    @commands.command()
    async def balance(self, ctx):
        await open_account(ctx.author)
        user = ctx.author
        users = await get_bank_data()

        wallet_amt = users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
        bank_amt = users[str(user.id)]["bank"] = 0

        em = discord.Embed(title=f"{ctx.author.name}'s balance", colour = discord.Color.green())
        em.add_field(name = "Wallet balance", value = wallet_amt)
        em.add_field(name = "Bank balance", value = bank_amt)

        await ctx.send(embed=em)

    @commands.command()
    async def beg(self, ctx):
        await open_account(ctx.author)

        users = await get_bank_data()
        user = ctx.author
        earnings = random.randrange(123)

        await ctx.send(f"Someone gave you {earnings} coins!")


        users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] += earnings
        with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(users,f)




    async def open_account(self, user):

        users = await get_bank_data()
        

        if str(user.id) in users:
            return False
        else:
            users[str(user.id)] = {}
            users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
            users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0


        with open("mainbank.json","w") as f:
            json.dump(users,f)
        return True

    async def get_bank_data():
        with open("mainbank.json","r") as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        return users






def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(Economy(client))
```

Comment: Mind linking the tutorial link? I'm kinda interested in seeing it

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HPaadO_sRD4&ab_channel=CodeWithSwastik
This is the tutorial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `open_account` function is a method of the `Economy` class. To call it from a different method of the same class, you have to do `await self.open_account(ctx.author)`.

Comment: Thank you! I worked, I did the same to get_bank_data. And it fixed all problems